# Why doesn't my gedit(ubuntu 12) have an edit button

Tags: gedit, preferences

Hello I'm pretty much a newbie with linux, and I have decided I want to use gedit with some addons for developing "ruby on rails" sites. The problem I'm having is that my gedit has no edit-button and i swear i can't find it anywhere. Why is that?

Comment: what do you mean with 'edit button'? What is the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: you don't need Edit button , just **Start Editing**, or you dont have save button ?

Comment: I need to add a color scheme and I should enter `preferences`. This should be under `edit` button

Comment: In the Unity user interface, the menus appear at the top of the screen.  When you mouse over the top bar, you should see the `Edit` menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening up gedit, try the following,

```
Alt+e
```

And the 'edit' drop down menu should appear unless something is really wrong.